# Tablet report as charging with the charger unplugged

Tags: samsung, charging

I'm having problems charging my Samsung Tab 2 device. It is reporting as charging after I unplug the cable, and when charging, it is drawing a small current from the charger. I've measured and it gets stuck at 500mA.

When I use the fix of "pressing all the keys during 10 seconds" that is supposed to reset the charging circuitry, the charging process becomes ok, I believe, and it then draws over 1 Amp but, if I unplug/plug again, the situation repeats, and it then begins just drawing a fixed 500mA value.

Basically, when I disconnect the charging cable, somehow, the device becomes erratic.

Comment: are you somehow using a custom kernel?

Comment: Yes, Syakur, I'm using Cyanogen mod.